# Layout or View for creating forms in MAUI

Tags: maui

Which is the most appropriate layout or view for creating a form like page in MAUI? Especially where multiple user input fields are to be accommodated and which will require scrolling.

Coming from native iOS programming where I've been using the static TableView to design such a form view.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question will likely lead to opinion-based answers and may be closed. There is no "most appropriate" way, it depends on the context and your personal preference.

Comment: To get a good answer, please do more research first. Try to solve the problem yourself. If you get stuck, then show a **specific example**. Show a mockup of the desired result. Show code as far as you could take it. Describe what detail you are stuck on. If you find two different possible approaches, try to get both of them to work. Don't ask "most appropriate" (that is considered "opinion"). Identify a specific problem or limitation, and focus on that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a new ContentPage, the outer most element should be Grid.
2. Add ScrollView to the Grid.
3. Add VerticalStackLayout to the ScrollView.
4. Add Labels and Inputs to the VerticalStackLayout.

This will do what you are asking for.

The following is my opinion, feel free to ignore it:

Those days, when designing mobile apps, people do not force the users to scroll, by placing all the inputs in one page. Instead, the user is guided through different steps. As a programmer, you may consider this an extra work to be done. For the user, this flow is much more friendly than endless scrolling up and down.

Comment: Is the Grid to ensure that the ScrollView fills the height of the screen?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have grid-fetish. Everything I do, I start from grids. And yes, their fit to screen feature is one of the best features. But I also do it to make design responsive. Lets say this form has submit button, and you want it always visible at the bottom of the screen. New row, 10% weight, place the button and fill. One line of code, looks good on all phones.